# PHP Download Button Not Working Generate Empty File

Tags: php, html, forms

I have two button in the form, one is to submit and second button download the output shown in the textarea.

The submit works fine but download button create empty file and does not write data of output text area.

Here is code:

```
<?php    
error_reporting(0);
$mytext = "";

$txt = preg_replace('/\n+/', "\n", trim($_POST['inputtext']));
$text = explode("\n", $txt);
$output  = array();


if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($text);$i++)
    {
        $output[] .= trim($text[$i]) . ' Text added with output'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}


if(isset($_POST["download"]) ) {

    $handle = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    fwrite($handle, implode($output));
    fclose($handle);

    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.basename('file.txt'));
    header('Expires: 0');
    ob_end_clean();
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('file.txt'));
    readfile('file.txt');
    exit;
}   
?>


<form method="POST" action="test.php">
<textarea name="inputtext" rows="10" cols="100" placeholder="Enter Any Text!" required><?php if(!empty($_POST["inputtext"])) { echo $_POST["inputtext"]; } ?></textarea>
<br><br>
<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Do it!">
<br><br>
<p>Output goes here. </p><textarea name="oputputtext" rows="10" cols="100" ><?php echo implode($output);?></textarea>
<input type="submit"   name="download" value="Download Output">
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure `$output` is not empty? Have you tried using `print_r(implode($output));` ? because this is what you write on your file

Comment: First mistake `error_reporting(0);` **If you have bugs turn error reporting on**

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: `$output[] .= ` ???

Comment: print_r(implode($output));
Yes this output result....

Comment: Don't edit your question to remove the code. Without the code, your question does not help others who might have the same problem.

Comment: Stop rolling back our edits Susi. Removing code from your question is not going to help you (in fact, no code is a good reason to close a question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to generate the output also if downloading (unless you take it from the second textarea), so use `if(isset($_POST["submit"]) || isset($_POST["download"]) )` in the test, instead of only `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))`

The final code would look like this:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
$mytext = "";

$txt = preg_replace('/\n+/', "\n", trim($_POST['inputtext']));
$text = explode("\n", $txt);
$output  = array();


/* CHANGED HERE */

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) || isset($_POST["download"]) ) {


    for($i=0;$i<count($text);$i++) {

        $output[] .= trim($text[$i]) . ' Text added with output'.PHP_EOL;

    }

}


if(isset($_POST["download"]) ) {

    $handle = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    fwrite($handle, implode("\r",$output));
    fclose($handle);

    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename('file.txt'));
    header('Expires: 0');
    ob_end_clean();
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('file.txt'));
    readfile('file.txt');
    exit;
}   

?>


<form method="POST" action="test.php">
    <textarea name="inputtext" rows="10" cols="100" placeholder="Enter Any Text!" required><?php if(!empty($_POST["inputtext"])) { echo $_POST["inputtext"]; } ?></textarea>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Do it!">
    <br><br>
    <p>Output goes here. </p>
    <textarea name="oputputtext" rows="10" cols="100" ><?php echo implode($output);?></textarea>
    <input type="submit"   name="download" value="Download Output">
</form>
```