# Php Textbox output is printing instead of downloading

Tags: php, download

This problem is different of the other question problem. That problem was about IF condition. But this problem, instead of downloading file, it is printing on next page. Please don't confuse this question with others.

I have wrote a script which download output of text box. This script works fine on local server, it download the file successfully  but when I put script on live server, the download file does not work. When `download output` button is clicked, instead of downloading file the output of page is shown on next page.

See live script here: http://www.globalitsoft.net/scripts/test.php

Here is the code of script:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(0);
    $mytext = "";

    $txt = preg_replace('/\n+/', "\n", trim($_POST['inputtext']));
    $text = explode("\n", $txt);
    $output  = array();        

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]) || isset($_POST["download"]) ) {        
        for($i=0;$i<count($text);$i++) {    
            $output[] .= trim($text[$i]) . ' AAAAA'.PHP_EOL;    
        }    
    }

    if(isset($_POST["download"]) ) {
      ob_clean();   
      $filename = "file-name-" .date('mdY-His'). '.txt';                    
      $handle = fopen('php://output', "w");
      fwrite($handle, implode($output));
      fclose($handle);
      header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
      header("Content-type: application/force-download");
      header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream charset=utf-8");
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
      header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
      header('Expires: 0');
      header('Pragma: public');
      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
      header('Content-Length: ' . strlen(implode($output)));
      readfile($filename);

      exit();        
    }     
?>


<form method="POST" action="test.php">
    <textarea name="inputtext" rows="10" cols="100" placeholder="Enter Any Text!" required><?php if(!empty($_POST["inputtext"])) { echo $_POST["inputtext"]; } ?></textarea>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Do it!">
    <br><br>
    <p>Output goes here. </p>
    <textarea name="oputputtext" rows="10" cols="100" ><?php echo implode($output);?></textarea>
    <input type="submit"   name="download" value="Download Output">
</form>
```

Comment: well `error_reporting(0);` that didn't help you; you need to set that to catch and display

Comment: didn't you post this already? http://stackoverflow.com/q/43941102/1415724 and received an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Download Button Not Working Generate Empty File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43941102/php-download-button-not-working-generate-empty-file)

Comment: No this is not duplicated. That was about if condition regarding download button.. But this is about downloading file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "w");
fwrite($handle, "text1.....");
fclose($handle);

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
//You dont need to enclose the filename value in quotes
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename('file.txt'));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('file.txt'));
readfile('file.txt');
exit;
```

Comment: This works but if i add header which if it only has this html tag <html></html> then it does not create download file instead it print like the above link i gave...